# Error 500 on providerType invalid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, postgresql, mono

I'm learning to develop an EntityFramework/PostgreSQL/C# web and I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> The parameter 'providerType' is invalid
>
> Parameter name: providerType
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.
>
> Exception stack trace:
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.RegisterBuildProvider (System.String extension, System.Type providerType) [0x00047] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildProvider.cs:146
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start () [0x0000e] in :0
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start () [0x0000e] in :0
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>
> at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295

Is this related to the Web.config? (I've had some problem making it work)

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="pgConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=gestiontienda;User Id=[username];Password=[Password];" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Although you are accessing a local server, you left username and password information in your connection string, its usually best to omit that information.

I looked up a working example I have. Here is the provider definition that works for me. 

`<provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />`

[Here's the nuget package:](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/)

Comment: Additionally, I believe you need Mono.Security.dll referenced in your project with Npgsql and EntityFramework as well. You should verify that its part of your project.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mind the user/password. It's only for development.
I'll try it later (now Win10 has screwed grub).